# Android overflow menu text not appearing

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to put a checkable overflow menu into my toolbar. The menu renders with the check boxes, but the text does not appear. Android studio renders the menu as intended but it does not on my AVD. I have tried changing the text color of the menu and using an action layout.

[![Intended render of menu][1]][1]

[![Actual render of menu][2]][2]

menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/tab_1"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="@string/tab_1"
            app:showAsAction="never|withText"
            android:actionLayout="@layout/action_layout"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/tab_2"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="@string/tab_2"
            android:visible="true"
            app:showAsAction="never|withText" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/tab_3"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="@string/tab_3"
            android:visible="true"
            app:showAsAction="never|withText" />


</menu>
```

activity_main.kt

````
    lateinit var sectionsPagerAdapter: SectionsPagerAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
        val viewPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
        viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
        val tabs: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        val toolBar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tool_bar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar)
        toolBar.showOverflowMenu()


        var position: Int = 0

        class onTabSelectListen : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                if (tab != null) {
                    position = tab.position
                };
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                Log.d("","")
            }

            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab){
                position = tab.position;
            }
        }



        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectListen())

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Reloading...", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
            fab.animate()
                .setDuration(500)
                .rotationBy(-360f)
            reload()
        }


    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        val itemId = item.itemId

        if (item.isChecked) {
            //TODO("UNCHECKD LOGIC")
            item.isChecked = false //Toggles checkbox state.
        } else {
            //TODO("CHECKED LOGIC")
            item.isChecked = true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    fun reload(){
        (sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(sectionsPagerAdapter.GOOGLE_POSITION) as WebFragment).reloadWebView()
        (sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(sectionsPagerAdapter.TWITTER_POSITION) as WebFragment).reloadWebView()
    }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEOFd.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqjwb.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Try setting following property in Item:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Instead of:

```
app:showAsAction="never|withText"
```

Comment: The text shows but this is not the intent of the UI. The menu items should be in an overflow menu, not as buttons on the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an attribute under `<toolbar>` worked for me

```
app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Assignment1.PopupOverlay"
```